# The analytic extension of the function $|x|$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(x) = |x|$, for $x \in \mathbb R$. What is the analytic extension of the function $f$ to the domain $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: Are you sure there is one?

Comment: I don't know if it is $\sqrt{z^2}$?

Comment: How would you define $\sqrt{z^2}$ on the given domain?

Answer (score 5):

By the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), if $f$ is an analytic function on a connected open set $U$ that intersects $(0,\infty)$ and such that $f(z) = z$ on that intersection, then $f(z) = z$ on all of $U$. So there is no such extension.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What is the analytic extension of the function $f$ to the domain $\mathbb C \setminus [0, i \infty)$? Is it $\sqrt{z^2}$?

Comment: Didn't you read what I wrote?  It is $z$.